# Concatenating Columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate several columns which mostly contain NaNs to one, but here is an example on 2 only:

```
2013-06-18 21:46:33.422096-05:00  A    NaN
2013-06-18 21:46:35.715770-05:00  A    NaN
2013-06-18 21:46:42.669825-05:00  NaN    B
2013-06-18 21:46:45.409733-05:00  A    NaN
2013-06-18 21:46:47.130747-05:00  NaN    B
2013-06-18 21:46:47.131314-05:00  NaN    B
```

This could go on for 3 or 4 or 10 columns, always 1 being `pd.notnull()` and the rest are NaN.

I want to concatenate these into 1 column the fastest way possible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get one string per line and the other cells are `NaN`, then the math to apply is to ask for the `max` value:

```
 df.max(axis=1)
```

As per comment, if it doesn't work in Python 3, project your `NaN` into strings before:

```
df.fillna('').max(axis=1)
```

Comment: FYI this won't work in python 3.  I can't remember the details but I they changed the comparison of strings and numerics.  In python 3 it returns all nans.

Comment: @TomAugspurger thank you for the remark, I amended the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
In [278]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, np.nan], [2, np.nan], [np.nan, 3]])

In [279]: df
Out[279]: 
    0   1
0   1 NaN
1   2 NaN
2 NaN   3

In [280]: df.sum(1)
Out[280]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: float64
```

Since `NaN`s are treated as 0 when summed, they don't show up.

A couple of caveats:  You need to be sure that *only* one of the columns has a non-Nan for this to work.  It will also only work on numeric data.

You can also use

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

The last column will now contain all the valid observations since the valid ones have been filled ahead. See the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).  The second way should be more flexible but slower.  I slice off every row and the last column with `iloc[:, -1]`.

Comment: So I will try the 2nd option, but I'm so surprised there isn't an easier option. This is literally just concatting again, but just with columns instead of dataframes.